# Flutter - aligning wrapped text right

Tags: flutter, dart, alignment

I have this column of widgets. They are containers with a row for the label and text.
On a big enough screen size, it looks nice.

[image: Big screen]

However, when I decrease the screen size, the text starts to wrap and it aligns left.

[image: Small screen]

I want it to keep staying to the right and be aligned with the other texts. Is there a way to do it?

Here's the widget code:

```
const LrListItem({Key? key, required this.label, required this.text})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: bPadding25,
      child: Container(
        height: 40,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border(
          bottom: BorderSide(width: 1, color: lrDarkBlue.withOpacity(0.3)),
        )),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              width: 150,
              child: BoxText(
                text: label,
                size: 16,
                color: lrDarkBlue.withOpacity(0.3),
              ),
            ),
            Flexible(
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                child: BoxText(
                  text: text,
                  size: 16,
                  color: lrDarkBlue,
                  lines: 2,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I tried Wrap, Expanded, Flexible and Align, but nothing quite worked.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          SizedBox(width: 150, child: Text(label1)),
          Flexible(
            child: RichText(
                text: WidgetSpan(
              child: Text(
                label2,
                textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
              ),
            )),
          )
        ],
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep the text right aligned use

```
Text("Your text", textAlign: TextAlign.right),
```

To restrict the text to one line use

```
Text("Your text", textAlign: TextAlign.right, maxLines: 1),
```

To not get text overflow errors use

Text("Your text", textAlign: TextAlign.right, maxLines: 1, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),